# I need to create a list of folders that contain a specific file type with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Using a batch file I'm trying to generate a list of only folders within a location that contain a certain file type, let's call it *.abc

at the moment I only know how to echo a DIR command output to a file called folder.lst, I would like to expand on that and try to either

a) echo only folders containing the *.abc file type to folder.lst
b) remove references in folder.lst of folders that do not contain the *.abc file type.

I also tried having a FOR loop check each line to see if a *.abc file existed in that location and skip it, if not, but I just could not get that to work, here is an example of what I had.

```
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

FOR /F "delims=" %%C in (folder.lst) do (
set temp=%%C
if not exist !temp!\*.abc (goto skip) else (goto resume)
:resume
```

then my actions live here

```
:skip
)
```

but I am aware I am doing something wrong here...I just do not know what.

Comment: Tell us what didn't work. Were there any error messages? What did you expect to happen? What actually happened?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `/R` form of the `for` command will help:

```
for /r "basedir" %%a in (.) do if exist "%%~a\*.abc" (
    echo %%a contains .abc file(s)
)
```

The `%%a` will be the directories you want (with a trailing `\.`, but you should be able to not care or accommodate this).

Answer (score 0):

**From the command line**:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir /s /b *.abc') do echo %~dpa >> folders.lst
```

**In a batch file**:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.abc') do echo %%~dpa >> folders.lst
```

The above commands will place only the folder names containing the `*.abc` files in `folders.lst`.

**Notes**:

- `%` should be replaced by `%%` when the command is used in a batch file.
- The `~dp` part of `%~dpa` expands `%a` to a drive letter and path only. Remove the `d` if you don't want the drive letter. The `p` path includes a trailing `\` which may be interpreted as an escape character by some commands.
- The above commands start the search in the current directory. To search from the root of the current drive you can do `cd \` first.

For more information see [FOR /F Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and [Parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html).

Answer (score 0):

There are problems with such of the script as you have posted in that you can'y use labels within a block statement. You've also not provided any examples.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "lastdir="
FOR /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*.abc) DO IF "!lastdir!" neq "%%~dpa" (
 SET "lastdir=%%~dpa"
 ECHO %%~dpa
 echo "!lastdir:~0,-1!"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Each directory found will be `echo`ed twice - one with the trailing `\` and once without.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "root=%cd%"

    for %%a in ("%root%") do for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%b in ('
        dir /a-d /s "%root%\*.abc" ^| find "\"
    ') do echo(%%~da%%~pnxb
```

This executes a recursive `dir` command searching for the indicated file type under the starting point (change `root` variable to suit your needs). For each found folder we retrieve the folder from the `dir` header that precedes the file list (the lines that contain a backslash).

To separate the path from the rest of the information in the line, the colon is used as delimiter. As this will leave the drive out of the retrieved information, an aditional `for` is used to retrieve the drive from the folder reference.